# Is It Possible to Store cv::Point to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to store Points to an opencv matrix (cv::Mat), is it possible or not?
I've tried it with this code:

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Point> matPoint;
matPoint.at<cv::Point>(0) = cv::Point(2,2);
std::cout << matPoint.at<cv::Point>(0) << std::endl;
```

Actually, it was compiled successfully, but when I run the code I got an "Floating point exception".
I know my above code is wrong, but I don't know the other way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You only need the `<cv::Point>` the first time (i.e. when declaring the `matPoint` variable. Change the `at` call to `at(0)`.

Comment: Also, you should specify dimensions for the matrix to ensure that there actually is a 0th-element: `cv::Mat_<cv::Point> matPoints(1,1);`

Comment: Interesting. Why is this a useful thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
// Create 1x1 matrix and initialize all elements with (0,0)
cv::Mat_<cv::Point> matPoint(1, 1, cv::Point(0, 0));

// Access the element with index 0
matPoint(0) = cv::Point(2, 2);

// Alternative syntax for targeting the elements by their two-dimensional index:
std::cout << matPoint(0, 0) << std::endl;
```

The `.at<cv::Point>(0)` syntax should also work but is less convenient.

Answer (score 2):

another version:

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Point> matPoint;
matPoint.push_back(Point(2,2));
```